# localizion doesn't work after changing the package name

Tags: android, localization

My application was working until I had this idea of changing the package name, and now the location doesn't work. the map is displayed and I am able to add markers on it. 
But the location is not working. HELP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ustolicence.guide_oran"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


 <permission
    android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />





<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.Rbt" 

     >




    <activity

        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
                    />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Rech"
        />

   <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Parcour"
        />
   <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Item"
        />
   <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.CustomGridView"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.ListFromSQLite"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Restaurant"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Dictionnary"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.DetailsFromTheList"
        />
    <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Activity_map"
        />

    <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Display_dict_on_list"
        />

   <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.MainActivity"
        />  
         <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Annuaire_call"
        />  
         <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.A_visiter"
        />  
        <activity
        android:name="com.ustolicence.guide_oran.Fill_tourist"
        />  


 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDzpyv7q9cExF63uAnkqCz9gKTXL9Oekww"/>

   </application>
   </manifest>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the location is not working"?

Answer (score 1):

When you are generating your application key for the Google Maps API V2, you need to specify the `SHA1` key and the package name of the application for example `xx:xx:xx...xx:xx;'yourPackageName'`. So each key is for one package name.
You need the generate new key. You can generate new key for you application with the same SHA1 and the new package name.
I hope that this will help you.

Comment: I don't have problem with the map.